# DateTime group by date and hour

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a datetime called **activity_dt** and the data looks like this:

```
2/5/2013 9:24:00 AM
2/7/2013 7:17:00 AM
```

How do i group by date and hour?

Comment: what rdbms that you used?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

SQL Server :

```
SELECT [activity_dt], count(*)
FROM table1
GROUP BY DATEPART(day, [activity_dt]), DATEPART(hour, [activity_dt]);
```

Oracle :

```
SELECT [activity_dt], count(*)
FROM table1
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(activity_dt, 'DD'), TO_CHAR(activity_dt, 'hh');
```

MySQL :

```
SELECT [activity_dt], count(*)
FROM table1
GROUP BY hour( activity_dt ) , day( activity_dt )
```

Comment: do you mean format the date like 2/5/2013 ? SELECT DATE_FORMAT( activity_dt , '%e/%c/%Y' )

Comment: Why do you use the square brackets? On mysql it's giving me a syntax error when I use them

Comment: @Jazerix: you don't need that..Actually square brackets is used if your column name contains space like `[activity dt]`

Comment: @IswantoSan - what's the best way to display the date & hour with each row for mysql?

Comment: Does not work in ms sql: Column 'Invoices.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @IswantoSan how can we define start time 8:00 and end time 18:00

Comment: @IswantoSan how we define start time and end time rang using am and pm?

Comment: this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Answer (score 26):

Using MySQL I usually do it that way:

```
SELECT count( id ), ...
FROM quote_data
GROUP BY date_format( your_date_column, '%Y%m%d%H' )
order by your_date_column desc;
```

Or in the same idea, if you need to output the date/hour:

```
SELECT count( id ) , date_format( your_date_column, '%Y-%m-%d %H' ) as my_date
FROM  your_table 
GROUP BY my_date
order by your_date_column desc;
```

If you specify an index on your date column, MySQL should be able to use it to speed up things a little.

Comment: I had to replace %h with %H, sorting with 0-24 works better for me instead of 0-12 & 0-12.

Comment: Just a note regarding index usage. While date_format does allow indexes to be used, indexes will only be optimally used (loose index scan) when specific/limited aggregate functions are used. Generally, only MIN() and MAX() applied to a single column allow for index scans, and also other aggregates as long as they specify DISTINCT keyword. Source: [link] (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [activity_dt], COUNT(*) as [Count]
  FROM 
 (SELECT dateadd(hh, datediff(hh, '20010101', [activity_dt]), '20010101') as [activity_dt]
    FROM table) abc
 GROUP BY [activity_dt]
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case... with MySQL:

`SELECT ... GROUP BY TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, HOUR(columName), DATE(columName))`